# JAGS: node inconsistent with parents

Tags: jags

I am trying to apply Benedict Escoto's method from the paper "Bayesian Claim Severity with Mixed Distributions," published in Variance. I seem to be running into a JAGS simulation problem. When I run the code, JAGS gives me the following error:

**Error in node ones[1] Node inconsistent with parents**

The data is two-fold. First, there is a list of ground-up insurance claims. Information on their age in years, deductibles (truncation) and whether they have been capped (censoring, True or False) is provided. Second, there is a list of prior means and corresponding probability weights for a mixed exponential distribution.

One thing I noticed is that it works for one set of data of priors for mixed exponential distribution, but fails for another.

It works with:

Mean Weight
 50 0.3
 100 0.25
 500 0.25
 1500 0.1
 5000 0.07
 20000 0.03

But it fails with:

Mean Weight
 3 0.72
 14 0.19
 42 0.05
 138 0.02
 503 0.01
 1501 0.01

So it may have to do with parameter requirements for mixed exponential.

Data packet for JAGS is assembled as below

```
jags.data <- list(claims=(claim.df$x[!claim.df$capped]
                      - claim.df$truncation[!claim.df$capped]),
              capped.claims=(claim.df$x[claim.df$capped]
                      - claim.df$truncation[claim.df$capped]),
              alpha=alpha,
              means=actual.means,
              ones=rep(1, length(claim.df$[claim.df$capped])),                                                                                                                                  
              ages=claim.df$age[!claim.df$capped],
              capped.ages=claim.df$age[claim.df$capped],
              trend.shape=trend.shape,
              trend.rate=1/trend.scale)
```

Notice that object "ones" is given values of 1 for each capped claim.

The initial values are supplied as below:

```
jags.init <- list(means=list(weights=prior.weights),
              equal=list(weights=rep(1/m,m)))
```

Some miscellaneous values are provided as follows:

```
m <- length(actual.means)
alpha0 <- 20
alpha <- prior.weights * alpha0
trend.prior.mu <- .05
trend.prior.sigma <- .01
trend.scale <- trend.prior.sigma^2 / (1+trend.prior.mu)
trend.shape <- (1+trend.prior.mu)/trend.scale
```

The JAGS model is coded as below:

```
model <- "model {
  weights ~ ddirch(alpha)
  trend.factor ~ dgamma(trend.shape, trend.rate)
  for (i in 1:length(claims)) {
    buckets[i] ~ dcat(weights)
    mu[i] <- means[buckets[i]] / trend.factor^ages[i]
    claims[i] ~ dexp(1/mu[i])
  }
  for (i in 1:length(capped.claims)) {
    capped.buckets[i] ~ dcat(weights)
    capped.mu[i] <- means[capped.buckets[i]]/trend.factor^capped.ages[i]
    prob.capped[i] <- exp(-capped.claims[i]/capped.mu[i])
    ones[i] ~ dbern(prob.capped[i])
  }
}"
```

Dirichlet, Categorical and Gamma distributions are used for priors. Ones is Bernoulli distributed to characterize claims as capped or uncapped.

Finally, the model is run in JAGS with the following:

```
model.out <- autorun.jags(model, data=jags.data, inits=jags.init,
                      monitor=c("weights","trend.factor"),
                      startburnin=1000, startsample=5000,
                      n.chains=n.chains, interactive=FALSE, thin=thin.factor)
```

Would anyone have an idea what goes wrong? Thanks

Comment: The model is very difficult to understand because you haven't told us which variables are data and which variables are parameters and how the data are structured (or else you only want answers from people who are already familiar with that specific article). Have you tried letting JAGS initialize the chains by itself, that is, just leaving out explicit parameter initialization?

Comment: Mr. Kruschke, thank you for your response. I am currently following your textbook, Doing Bayesian Data Analysis, on this topic, it's very helpful. I edited my question to include more of the code for data, initial values and run. I tried letting JAGS initialize the object "ones" instead of assigning the 1 values, but the chains did not converge as a result. Mr, Escoto then pointed out that randomly initializing ones would be akin to making up random claims data, and would possibly explain the divergence. I'd appreciate your comments.

Comment: I meant commenting out `inits=jags.init,`  Will have to consider other details later when I have time...

Comment: This error is probably happening because `prob.capped[1]` is getting a value almost equal to zero (for the computer, an exact zero).  Therefore, the model crashes when tries to consider that the value 1 has been obtained from a Bernoulli(p=0).  To solve this, it is usually advisable to set some initial values for the priors that ensure that 0<<p<<1, and sometimes reducing the domain of the prior distributions also help.